# Managing HLSL effects

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl, directx-10

Let say, for this example, that I have **World** class. World has collection of **Models** :

```
class World
{
    public:
      map<string, Model*> Models;
};
```

Model would be abstract class for all entities in application, for example car, ball, mountain, or cube.

And the question is - what's the best practice for managing effects for that models. Let say, that I've got 4 effect files : **base1.fx, base2.fx, base3.fx, bas4.fx**. Each of them has class interface, which might be bound to model ( **IBaseEffect1, IBaseEffect2, IBaseEffect3, IBaseEffect4** ).

Now, should I consider each model independent, and do something like:

```
Cube1.Bind(IBaseEffect2);
Car.Bind(IBaseEffect3);
```

Where model would have ability to manage effect, so I would make:

```
World::Render()
{
    foreach model -> Render();
}
```

Which is actual solution for my engine.

Or better would be to manage effects independent, and do something like:

```
IBaseEffect1.SetAsActual();

foreach Model which should be considered for effect1 -> Render();

IBaseEffect2.SetAsActual();

foreach Model which should be considered for effect2 -> Render();
```

etc...

Maybe my whole point of view is wrong, and it should be made other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use both of your methods. That is:

1. Each model has got its own effect bound: `model->Bind(effect);`
2. You manage the effects separately (for efficiency reasons):

   1. Sort models by the effects they're using
   2. For each effect:

      - Set up the effect
      - Render all models associated with the current effect

Models which have to be rendered in a fixed order (e.g. transparent objects) should be processed in a different way unless  all of them share the same effect.

Comment: That's what I have expected. Thank You for confirmation and answer